# Rebuilt jstree with selected nodes using checkbox plugin and Json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, jstree, rebuild

I am new to jstree, so guys please help in this.

I have build a jstree using json data and checked boxes. Now i want to reproduce the jstree again but this time with only checked nodes in the tree with same child- parent relationship.

I have used this as an example http://mattfrear.com/2011/12/17/jstree-revisited/

I have also used following:

```
$('#Tree').jstree("get_unchecked", null, true).each
(function () {    
     $('#Tree').jstree("remove", this);
});
```

to remove the unchecked nodes from the jstree, After this i got the tree with checked nodes only for a while and then again the tree refreshed to the actual json data and showing all the nodes of jstree including the unchecked nodes.

Any help, will be highly appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cookies plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/cookies) to preserve clicked checkboxes.

Comment: @ Radek, thanks for reply.... Actually i got the desired result with the code above mentioned by me itself. The actual reason of the page refreshing was the @using(Html.BeginForm()) statement in mvc3 view with redirects to the particular action method of a particular controller passed as arguments to this method.

Comment: I would like to add regarding cookies, what about your tree if the client disable cookies of the browser ? Then cookies will not work at all.